# In distributed training, is SessionRunHook only happening in master？

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

When using the tf_learn.Experiment(...) interface, we can pass in train_monitors and eval_hooks, are these hooks only happening in master?

I tried to read the source code and it shows that it should run the hook on every session.run(..). I believe not only master but also worker will run session.run(...). However, from the log result at cloud ml, I only see this hooks being run in master.

Can you someone explain this? Is there any document about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [`learn_runner.run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/learn_runner/run) in your script, a different method on [`Experiment`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) gets called depending on whether the node is a Master or Worker:

- On the Master, [`train_and_evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment#train_and_evaluate) is invoked.
- On workers, [`train`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment#train) is invoked.

`train_and_evaluate` eventually calls `train`, so in both cases, `train_monitors` are passed on to [`Estimator.train`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#train). However, evaluation occurs only on the Master, so `eval_hooks` are only run there.